# E_STORE_USER_FAILURE_83090C25, CsOpenStream failed with error 0x83090C25 (Alki User Error: New nodes are being created at too high a rate)

Tags: azure

I have a **Azure data factory** that is running a **U-SQL script** on **Azure Data Lake (gen1)**. The script reads Application insights data, and do some transformation on them and write them back into 1 file per day.
I've assigned **5 AUs** to the U-SQL and ran it for **10 days** of my **TEST** data. It failed with this error:

> "errorCode": "2703",
>       "message": "Error Id: E_STORE_USER_FAILURE_83090C25, Error Message: CsOpenStream failed with error 0x83090C25 (Alki User Error: New nodes are being created at too high a rate). Cosmos Path:

Why?!!! Isn't it created to handle big data? 
Then Also how to fix it?

P.S: when I run the same job/dates with 3AUs its working, but its going to take forever on production to work with 3 AUs :\

Comment: Did you [open a support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/)? What was the resolution of your ticket?

Comment: Yes,still waiting for their answser